# Reuse Natvis STL visualization fields in custom visualization

Tags: c++, std-function, type-erasure, natvis

##### Question

When writing custom Natvis visualizations for Visual Studio, (how) can I access fields of a lambda wrapped in a `std::function`?

##### Concrete example

I have a class looks somewhat like this (very simplified):

```cpp
class VariableVector {
public:
  // Constructor for returning values from captured vector
  Variable(const std::vector<double>& values)
    : m_valueGetter{[&values](int index) { return values[index]; }}
    {}
  
  // Constructor for always returning a constant value
  Variable(double value)
    : m_valueGetter{[value](int index) { return value; }}
    {}

  double operator[](int index) {
    return m_valueGetter(index);
  }
  
private:
  std::function<double(int)> m_valueGetter;
}
```

It uses a `std::function` to hide different implementations for how to get the values.

I now would like to display the values in the debugger using a custom `.natvis` file. As function calls are not allowed, I need to access the variables captured in the lambdas. How can I do that?
This is the closest I could get:

```
<Type Name="VariableVector">
  <DisplayString>(*m_valueGetter._Mystorage._Ptrs[9])</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

It shows me e.g. `{value: 42}` in the debugger. In the raw view, this element has a `_Callee` member which has the `value` field. However,

```
<Type Name="VariableVector">
  <DisplayString>(*m_valueGetter._Mystorage._Ptrs[9])._Callee</DisplayString>
</Type>
```

already gives me an error.

If it's nothing too major, I could also change the structor of my `VariableVector`, but I need the type erasure...

Comment: Aside: Unless you have a typo, the first lambda has a dangling reference. `values` ceases to exist before you can use `m_valueGetter`